# How do I configure the whitelist for MediaWiki?

Tags: php, wamp, mediawiki, whitelist

So I got stuck maintaining a MediaWiki while the person who set it up is away, and I know nothing about it, not even where its stored on the server (though I suspect in the wamp/www folder).  I was asked to add a few pages to the whitelist so they could be viewed without logging in.  [I found the MediaWiki manual page on whitelist](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgWhitelistRead), but it doesn't say where to put that snippet of code.  Which file(s) gets that treatment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out where your MediaWiki installation is and then add the pages that you want to the end of the LocalSettings.php file like this:

```
$wgWhitelistRead[] = "Page_name";
$wgWhitelistRead[] = "Another_page_name";
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I went with a slight variation to save space: `$wgWhitelistRead =  array ("item 1", "item 2", ... );`